# Bower with Visual Studio Publish

Tags: asp.net, tfs, npm, visual-studio-2015, bower

I want to use Bower in an MVC 4 application, developed in Visual Studio 2015. I know when you have a MVC 5 project, with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, there is a nice UI for Bower management, much like the nuget interface. This part is not really critical.

I am using bower currently - I have npm and bower setup, and I have the package.json and bower.json files in the solution.  When you save, Visual Studio automatically runs "npm install" and I have a postinstall step in package.json to run "bower install".

I do not want to put the bower_components into the solution (or source control).  What I want is to just keep the json config files, and when you save, all dependencies are retrieved.

This all works fine in development, but what doesn't work is right clicking the Web Project, Publish. Publish does not run "npm install", and does not include files not included in the solution (except it seems to work with nuget packages not included in the solution somehow). The "Publish Web" functionality is how my web applications are deployed to production using IIS deployment.

How can I make Visual Studio Web Publish work with Bower?

An alternative - I have seen there are new hooks for Team System Builds that will run gulp tasks, but I don't know that you can publish directly to IIS in this manner.

Comment: In mvc5 isn't just the www folder published. Meaning, your bower components wouldn't get published because it's NOT in the www folder.

Comment: @SteveKennedy - I think you are saying the same problem would exist with an MVC5 project?

Comment: @SteveKennedy I think you're thinking of MVC6 / ASP.NET 5.  MVC4 and 5 didn't have the wwwroot concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of referencing/deploying the complete bower_components folder, you can use a gulp or grunt script (pick whatever you prefer) to copy the correct files out of the bower_components folder to something like scripts/lib.

You can then include these files in source control and subsequently deploy them.

The following is a grunt file that I use to accomplish this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                  {
                      expand: true,
                      flatten: true,
                      src: [
                          'node_modules/vss-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js',
                          'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
                          'node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js',
                          'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                          'bower_components/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js',
                          'bower_components/datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css',
                      ],
                      dest: 'scripts/lib',
                      filter: 'isFile'
                  }              
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-exec");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
};
```

Comment: Yes I now, but I need this to work with the Web Publish feature in Visual Studio. It does alot more, including deploying to a remote IIS Server via http.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use Web Deploy. I'm suggesting you move the specific files from your bower directory to the source tree of your project and include these specific files in your project. They will then be deployed with Web Deploy.

Comment: I see. I realize I could do that, but I am specifically trying to avoid this. I do not want the bower components in the solution or source control, just the bower.json referencing the necessary components. Sorry if that wasn't clear.  EDIT - I think what you are suggesting is a bit different, you're suggesting to keep the "dist" files only in the solution, and they are put there by the gulp task?

Comment: yes! that's what I'm suggesting. You shouldn't include your whole bower_components folder. That would be messy. Instead, you pick the files you need and copy to a destination folder that is under source control. Grunt and Gulp can do this. The example above is a Grunt script.

Comment: Here in the future, I'm trying this, and the file (jquery.mask.js) is getting copied into my Scripts folder (from a bower_components sub-folder), but the dang Publish tool isn't copying it to the 'Publish To' (if you will) directory.  :(

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.NET Core (ie MVC6), Bower is configured (in a .bowerrc file) to add scripts to wwwroot/lib rather than a bower_components folder. That content does get published by Visual Studio.

The same approach using .a bowerrc file will work for MVC4 webs (at least if you are using Visual Studio 2015). However, it also gets checked into version control so it might not be exactly what you want.

The .bowerrc file can be used to do various things (see http://bower.io/docs/config/). However, to get Bower to add scripts to the project in ~/scripts/lib, you simply add the following json:

```
{
  "directory": "scripts/lib"
}
```

Comment: i saw that,but I don't want all of that content. the bower package is all the source files, build files, and dist files. all you really want included with your release is the dist files you are using so you need something like gulp to grab what you want (and concat/minify etc). really the deploy needs a hook for gulp or grunt like the new TFS Build seems to have. But the deploy has nice capabilities for deploying directly to an IIS site...

Comment: How about using a gulp command in the project post-build event hook to extract what you want then?