# Broken CSS Link When Published in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I have problem when publishing a Visual Studio 2017, C#, ASP.Net MVC 5 project. I do publish with following settings :

[image]
[image]

Problem with the CSS content link, for example bootstrap :

```
@font-face{font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';src:url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot);
```

If the bootstrap.min.css located in `localhost/bower_components/css/bootstraps/bootstrap.min.css`, that css will displayed as `localhost/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` at client.

If I just copy paste all project without publish it to the server, the link will displayed correctly as `localhost/bower_components/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`

This is happens for all css including images and other file in css.

Comment: Do the css files get copied to the `bower_components` folder in the publish output? And do the font files also get copied into the `bower_components` folder? In other words, is the direcorty listing in the publish output folder correct.

Comment: @ariekanarie Yes, all files copied succesfully when published.

Comment: I don't have solution, so just some things to check. There must be some difference in het file/folder-structure when you copy by hand en when you use the publish method.
Does disabling pre-compile help?

Comment: Is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34517032/495455

Comment: @Jeremy because I put it inside www folder, so it will included when published. And no, this is not related to bower_components. It is happens also outside bower. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 5):

With what is available of code knowledge in your question and what shown and explained. I can see in your code your relative path has the issue.

You are using `../` change it to `./` or `~/`. That should fix the issue.

By using `../` you are stepping the css path over.

Comment: `../` meaning parent directory and it will working great actually. Not meaning back to root. `/` is back to root directory. I think you read the question wrongly. Nothing wrong with the path since if I just copy all the code to the server, it will working great. Problem if I publish it. `../` act like `/` . Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the {YourProjectName}\App_Start\BundleConfig.Cs

Add Instance of **CssRewriteUrlTransform** Class when adding Bootstrap Bundle Like This:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
     StyleBundle bootCss = new StyleBundle("~/styles/bootstrap");
                      bootCss.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/styles/bootstrap.css", 
                      new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
     bootCss.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
     bundles.Add(bootCss);
}
```

Comment: Hi there this is doesnt work, actually all link is working great if I view the code in browser. It just act like `/` back to root directory which I want is back to parent directory. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Build action set to `None` by Default so you need to change it to `Content`.

Right click in affected file > properties > set `Build Action` to `Content`

I hope this can help

Comment: hi there, just like I said in comment, all files published correctly and Yes all files Build Action is Content, thats why all files copied correctly. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that some of my newly added files weren't publishing even though everything was set up correctly. I closed and reopened VS 2019 to find that the newly added files weren't added to the project. I remember a while ago the occasional need to go to `File` > `Save All`.

This is a simple solution, but hard to see when it's the issue.